# No module named 'six.moves.urllib'; 'six.moves' is not a package

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a Django server for a project, and I'm getting the following error.\

> No module named 'six.moves.urllib'; 'six.moves' is not a package

I've pip installed `six`, also I've verified it in python by importing `six.moves.urllib`.
I've also tried reinstalling `six`. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Check if you have file with same name `six`?

Comment: I didn't found any file with name ```six```. Also, I'm using a virtual environment.

Comment: Possibly installed it using `pip install six` and it's now installed for Python2.7 - but you're trying to run it using Python3.  Try `pip3 install six` -or- `python3 -m pip install six` instead.

Comment: Try "pip install urllib3" and "pip install urlopen".  It worked for me.